# Get keychain item with LAContext and touchIDAuthenticationAllowableReuseDuration

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, security, touch-id

I'm trying to add the functionality of `touchIDAuthenticationAllowableReuseDuration` to my app. I use Touch ID to authenticate a user into the app and at the same time recover an item from the keychain. Before I tried to add this there was no problem, it always asked for Touch ID or if not available for the device passcode. Now so far I've managed to make it so that it does the same thing, and when opening the app within the specified timeout it doesn't show the Touch ID prompt as it should, if all I was doing was authenticating the user I'd be done, but the problem that I'm having is that I also want to recover an item from the keychain, and when the prompt is bypassed with success, but once I call `SecItemCopyMatching(…)` I don't get the item back, instead I keep getting `errSecAuthFailed`.

I've looked online everywhere and the best thing I've found yet is Apple's sample code `KeychainTouchID`, but again, it doesn't do both authentication and getting an item from the keychain at the same time, I tried to add that to their code and I kept getting the same error as well.

Has anyone tried something like this before? How did you make it work? This is the code I have right now:

```
SecAccessControlRef sacObject = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(kCFAllocatorDefault, kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly, kSecAccessControlTouchIDAny, nil);

NSString *localizedReason = NSLocalizedString(@"Authenticate to access app", nil);

LAContext *context = [[LAContext alloc] init];
context.touchIDAuthenticationAllowableReuseDuration = 5;

[context evaluateAccessControl:sacObject operation:LAAccessControlOperationUseItem localizedReason:localizedReason reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    if (success) {
        NSDictionary *query = @{(__bridge id)kSecClass: (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword,
                                (__bridge id)kSecAttrService: PASSCODE_KEY,
                                (__bridge id)kSecReturnData: @YES,
                                (__bridge id)kSecUseOperationPrompt: localizedReason,
                                (__bridge id)kSecUseAuthenticationUI: (__bridge id)kSecUseAuthenticationUIAllow,
                                (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessControl: (__bridge_transfer id)sacObject,
                                (__bridge id)kSecUseAuthenticationContext: context
                                };

        CFTypeRef dataTypeRef = NULL;

        OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)(query), &dataTypeRef);
        // This works when using Touch ID / passcode, but I get errSecAuthFailed when the prompt isn't shown because of the reuse duration.
        if (status == errSecSuccess) {
            NSData *resultData = (__bridge_transfer NSData *)dataTypeRef;
            NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:resultData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            self.recoveredString = result;

        } else {
            self.recoveredString = @"";
        }
    } else {
        self.recoveredString = @"";
        CFRelease(sacObject);
    }
}];
```

Comment: Our team is having the exact same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Haven't found a solution yet unfortunately

Comment: I am having the same problem, with reuse, and accessing keychain. However, I always get prompted for touchid when calling SecItemCopyMatching. 
Your use of (__bridge id)kSecUseAuthenticationUI: (__bridge id)kSecUseAuthenticationUIAllow, should be redundant, as it is the default value. Have you figured out a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Don't create LAContext object each time. Just hold onto the LAContext object on which `evaluateAccessControl` has succeeded. That way you don't need to set `touchIDAuthenticationAllowableReuseDuration`. If you call `evaluateAccessControl` on a LAContext object on which `evaluateAccessControl` has already succeeded then reply callback is called immediately with success without user being asked to auth again

And when you want user to auth again, just invalidate the LAContext object.